# What folder/file do you execute rails server for ruby in cmd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cmd

I have been working through a few tutorials for ruby using cmd and sublime text, however I can not find any information that specifies which folder to open in cmd to launch rails server. I closed out the cmd mid tutorial and am trying to get back in to work on the app. I tried to launch rails server when in the script folder and the config etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run `rails server` from the root folder where you created your project.

Comment: C:\Sites\treebook>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/r
ailtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `assests' for #
<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x3a207b0> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Sites/treebook/config/application.rb:61:in `<class:Application>'

Comment: That's a typo in your `application.rb`. Should be 'assets' instead of 'assests'.

Comment: Thank you so much worked great :)

Comment: C:\Sites\treebook>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': C:/Sites/treebook/config/environm
ents/development.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (Sy
ntaxError)

Comment: Andrew, you have syntax errors in your code. The errors you are posting tell you exactly where to look. "C:/Sites/treebook/config/environments/development.rb:40" means line 40 of that file.